# Can't run artisan commands because vendor folder is not created

Tags: php, laravel

I've created a new project in laravel using the command

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel codebar
```

and when I type the command

```
php artisan serve
```

or

```
php artisan make:migration create_item_table
```

I have the error

```
Warning: require(D:\xampp\htdocs\codebar/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\codebar\artisan on line 18

Call Stack:
    0.0265     346928   1. {main}() D:\xampp\htdocs\codebar\artisan:0


Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'D:\xampp\htdocs\codebar/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\codebar\artisan on line 18

Call Stack:
    0.0265     346928   1. {main}() D:\xampp\htdocs\codebar\artisan:0
```

And my project folder don't have the vendor folder. SO i've tried commands like composer install, composer update, composer dump autoload and none of these have fix my problem.

Anyone can help me pls?

Answer (score 2):

You got an error because you have missing vendor folder in your project, You need /vendor because all your packages are there, including all the classes Laravel uses. The vendor directory contains your Composer dependencies.

Your problem can be resolved after following this step. you can try it:

```
composer update
```

With this command, you will re-create the vendor folder in your project and after that your project will start working normally.

Comment: Yes I know that that's the reason of my error and I will run your commands and after I give feedback

Comment: No problem, please accept our answer , if you find it useful.

Comment: Make sure you have composer.json and composer.lock file created at the root of your project. Run `composer install` from cli. This will install dependencies as well as create vendor directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have not executed 'composer update' after project setup. Run 'composer update' in your terminal and vendor folder will appear in root folder of your project.